# PHP Slim framework on NGINX with a specific location directive

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have Slim v4 framework installed with nginx/1.22.0 and php-fpm-8.1.9 on RHEL8. Here is the / location block of current nginx.conf that works fine.

```
  root /path/to/html/slim;

  location / {
     try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
  }
```

Instead of using `location /`, I'd like to use a different location for slim, so that / can be used to host another website. I tried below configuration, but slim gives me **404 Not Found** with `Slim\Exception\HttpNotFoundException`. Please help me to figure out a way. Thank you.

```
  root /path/to/html;

  location /slim {
     try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri =404;
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the exact path where the Slim `index.php` is and exact URL you want to use for it? Have you also configured the root URL correctly in Slim?

Comment: Slim `index.php` is in `/path/to/html/slim`. URL is supposed to be `http://x.x.x.x/slim/{api_path}`. Path is set in slim sample app as `$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) { ......... });`

Answer (score 0):

You should use full filesystem path with the `root` directive.

Also remember, nginx will append the path component of URL at the end of directory specified in `root`.

If your `root` is `/var/www/slim` in `/slim` location, then nginx will look up `https://example.com/slim/abc` in `/var/www/slim/slim/abc` location.

Comment: Thank you, @Tero! Actually I already have full paths for root and intentionally ignored them in my original question to make it looks simpler. Seems that made things confused, so I edited the question a bit. My particular issue exists even with full paths.